# Create Scatterplot data out of table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using `excel 2013` and have data in a tabular form:

[image]

I am trying to transfer the data into a row-format.

Using `Index-Match` I can match the row to the column values. However, I am struggling how to create the Row column (in **red**) to match my rows to the columns.

Any suggestions how to create the columns (Col and Rows) automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most Excel questions there are probably a multitude of different ways you could do it, here's two;

In cell M3 you could try any of the following and then drag them down;

`=IF(L3=0,IFERROR(M2+1,0),M2)` or `=COUNTIF($L$3:L3,L3)-1`